# How do I restart my score (reset static score) in reloading scene in unity?

Tags: c#, variables, static, unity-game-engine, reload

How do I restart my score when I reload a screen

```
public class KeepingScore: Monobehaviour;

public static int Score;
```

I also have score set as whenever I click on an object, the object is destroyed and gives me a point.

```
void OnMouseDown()

KeepingScore.score += 1;

Destroy();
```

I also have a timer where when I run out of time, scene switches to level select menu, where I click on the level again (ie level 1), but then I still see my score back how it was. I know it's static therefore It's still the same, are there any method to reset the value to zero every time I reload the level. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement the `MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded(int)` function.
It called every time that a level is loaded.

Example

```
void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
    KeepingScore.score = 0;
}
```

Check at the docs:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html

Comment: Also keep in mind that this event won't fire when you click the Play button to run the scene in the Editor.

Comment: Ok it worked, What I did was void OnLevelWasLoaded() { Keeping.Score = 0; }