# Unity DontDestroyOnload()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player is spawn in the position that he was in the previous level when the new scene is loaded. Is there any way to make a spawn point for this?

I used DoontDestoryOnLoad function to keep the player into the next scene but when the player loaded, the player will spawn in the same x position that he was.

public class DontDestroyPlz : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Use this for initialization
 void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

    if (FindObjectsOfType(GetType()).Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{

```
void OnGUI()
{


    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 1.5f, Screen.height / 8, Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 20), "Bunker"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Bunker");
    }


    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 3.5f, Screen.height / 2.65f, Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 20), "Forest"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Forest");
    }

    GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.magenta;
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 1.5f, Screen.height / 1.5f, Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 20), "Coming Soon!"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Desert");
    }

    GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.magenta;
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 3.0f, Screen.height / 1.5f, Screen.width / 8, Screen.height / 20), "Out of Service"))
    {
        //Application.LoadLevel("Swamp");
    }
}

public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log ("HERE BRUH!");
}

public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData data)
{

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restart my score (reset static score) in reloading scene in unity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934920/how-do-i-restart-my-score-reset-static-score-in-reloading-scene-in-unity)

Comment: This is a zillion-times duplicate - while an OK question, it's best answered by helpful answerers simply linking to a duplicate

Comment: jeffrey - I really, really, strongly recommend you do NOT use the "very old" gui system of Unity.  (1) it is incredibly difficult to use (2) the ordinary system Unity.UI is ridiculously easy to use (i, click 'canvas' ii, click 'add button'), (3) Unity are removing it soon and *your project will NOT work*.  There are ENDLESS excellent tutorials on UI, https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button?playlist=17111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method [OnLevelWasLoaded](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html). It will be called every time new scene is loaded. For example you can predifine player position for every scene:

```
Vector3 positionLevel1;
Vector3 positionLevel2;

void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) 
{
    if (level == 1)
       transform.position = positionLevel1;
    else if (level == 2)
       transform.position = positionLevel2;
}
```

Comment: in the main menu script or dontdestroy script? or just put it in player script?

Comment: I would suggest to put it on the player.

Comment: Powder, if possible consider not answering questions that are very trivial -- because they are always duplicates.  Just for what it's worth, you'll get more points by marking it as a duplicate.  There's a huge danger that this site will become as crap as the answers.unity3d site, due to the vast number of super-easy questions.

Comment: @JoeBlow Ok, I'll keep that in mind. I'll try to look for duplicates next time. Thanks

Comment: I'm new to unity, I don't even know what function i should be looking for. I just need some help here.......

Comment: Hi Jeffery, right you definitely **need a tutorial** .. https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=unity3d+tutorial+spawning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 fortunately there are many superb tutorials.  Go for it!